# Re-rendering currently on screen nodes in SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit, swift4, game-development

I'm very new to SpriteKit and game development in general, so I will try to phrase this the best way that I can.

I am currently trying to make a basic 2d side scroller game with SpriteKit to learn the basics of developing a game on the iPhone. I am trying to get into the concept of power ups, and essentially I want to redraw certain nodes that are already on the screen once the power up has been collected. I have all of the code working to register that the player has contacted the power up, and the adjustments are occurring on newly drawn nodes coming from off the screen, but the adjustments are not immediately occurring for nodes already on the screen. I have a circle around the nodes that I want to reduce the size of.

What I have been trying is to add code within the `update` method in `GameScene.swift` akin to:

```
if powerUp {
    for node in allNodesOnScreen {
        let nodeForEdit = node.childNode(withName: "nodeName") as? SKEffectNode
        for i in 0...3 {
            // Draw circle here (circle is in three parts)


            nodeForEdit?.addChild(circle)

        }
    }
}
```

Note: `allNodesOnScreen` is an array I add to once I draw any new nodes on the screen

I have been quite unsuccessful in getting this to work the way that I had hoped, and have been playing around with it as I have had crashes around adding nodes as children that already have parents (supposedly because they were already drawn on screen with a parent).

I'm very aware I may be immensely overcomplicating this, but any help would be really appreciated, and I'm happy to provide anymore information about what I've tried if it would help to clear things up.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in and trace your code?  You will probably see that nodeForEdit is nil

Comment: @Knight0fDragon - thanks for the response! I did spend some time tracing through, but I'm not sure I noticed this being nil. Is this what causes the error that the node already has the parent? Could you elaborate on what causes that node to be nil?